# How to store array data into redis in PHP

Tags: php, redis

In my project, I want to store array data into redis.

Here I use PHP.

First, It connects to redis successfully. And then I defined a array which name should be info_g_1.

Last, I use mset function to store this arry.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$redis_obj = \common\Datasource::getRedis('instance1');//connect to redis successfully
$id = '1';
$r_goods = 'info_g_' . $id;
$r_goods = array(
 'sys_status' => 'one',
 'num_user' => 'two'
);

$redis_obj->mset($r_goods);
```

But unlucky, It works fail. Thers is no info_g_1 data in my redis.

```
    $redis_obj->sadd('info_g_'.$id,'one');
    $redis_obj->sadd('info_g_'.$id,'two');
```

and fetch data:

```
    $redis_obj->smembers('info_g_'.$id); //can get one and two.
```

But this way, I am not sure whether one belongs to sys_status or num_user.

Who can help me?

Comment: `mset` __sets__ data, `r_goods` does not contain `info_g_1`. What's your question about?

Comment: you need to set somthing like this $redis->mset(array('yourKEY' => 'yourValue'));

Comment: As per the above code, if you search for 'sys_status' then you if find the value 'one'

Comment: @DsRaj, I want to set a array, not a key-value. If i choose $redis->mset(array('yourKEY' => 'yourValue'));  There will be many keys in redis. And it is not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in variable `$r_goods` is overwritten by array in next line in following code:

```
$r_goods = 'info_g_' . $id;
$r_goods = array(
 'sys_status' => 'one',
 'num_user' => 'two'
);
```

The actual value in `$r_goods` is:

```
array(
     'sys_status' => 'one',
     'num_user' => 'two'
    );
```

Also you can set it as:

```
$redis_obj->set('info_g_' . $id, 'value to store');
```

**Update:** To add multiple key-value pairs, `mset` can be used as set:

```
$redis_obj->mset($r_goods);
```

But if want to store array as values corresponding to key. Then need to `json_encode` array first & then set as follows:

```
$redis_obj->set('key', json_encode(array('sys_status' => 'one', 'num_user' => 'two')));
```

And can be retrieved as:

```
$array = json_decode($redis_obj->get('key'), true);
```

This reason behind this is, redis store only strings no other data type.

Comment: Actually, I want to set a array not a key-value. So set function can not fix my problem

Comment: Answer Updated!